# Display Sale Date from and Sale Date to

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I got this code from here ( [Display woocommerce sale end date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23329518/display-woocommerce-sale-end-date) )

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_html', 100, 2 );
function custom_price_html( $price, $product )
{
    global $post;
    $sales_price_to = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_sale_price_dates_to', true);
    if(is_single() && $sales_price_to != "")
    {
        $sales_price_date_to = date("j M y", $sales_price_to);
        return str_replace( '</ins>', ' </ins> <b>(Offer till '.$sales_price_date_to.')</b>', $price );
    }
    else
    {
        return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_price', $price );
    }
}
```

This only displays the Sale Date to. How do I make it display the sale date from till sale date to?

I tried editing this line:

```
return str_replace( '</ins>', ' </ins> <b>(Offer till '.$sales_price_date_to.')</b>', $price );
```

to

```
return str_replace( '</ins>', ' </ins> <b>(Offer from '.$sales_price_date_from.' till '.$sales_price_date_to.')</b>', $price );
```

but it doesn't display the sale date from.

So can someone please tell me how I display both the sale date from and sale date to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried it on my site and it works for me.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_html', 100, 2 );
function custom_price_html( $price, $product ) {

    $sales_price_from = get_post_meta( $product->id, '_sale_price_dates_from', true );
    $sales_price_to   = get_post_meta( $product->id, '_sale_price_dates_to', true );

    if ( is_single() && $product->is_on_sale() && $sales_price_to != "" ) {

        $sales_price_date_from = date( "j M y", $sales_price_from );
        $sales_price_date_to   = date( "j M y", $sales_price_to );

        $price = str_replace( '</ins>', ' </ins> <b>(Offer from ' . $sales_price_date_from . ' till ' . $sales_price_date_to . ')</b>', $price );
    }

    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_price', $price );
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, it causes my page to crash and I am unable to see my website. Can you paste me the full code that you tried? I'll try see if that works.

Comment: Could you enable WP_DEBUG then paste the error here ?

Comment: I tested your code again, I realised I didnt delete the old code, thus, the error occured. Your code works perfectly! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a plugin exactly for this (100% free, no ads and no hidden features).

The main difference from others on the store is that it also works with Variations (even if each variation has different dates).

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-on-sale-information/

Also, it was developed with simplicity in mind and with filters for developers to be able to tweak it without issues (the code is well documented also).

Give it a look ;)