# How to display sales date in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

In Woocommerce, I am trying to display the sales date of a variable product.

I found [a code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40711914/display-sale-date-from-and-sale-date-to), if I post this code exactly in functions.php it doesn't do anything. I tried to modify it, because I need it only on the start page, but the `var_dump` returns an empty string. Maybe I have to add an argument?

```
<?php
$meta_query  = WC()->query->get_meta_query();
$tax_query   = WC()->query->get_tax_query();
$tax_query[] = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
    'field'    => 'name',
    'terms'    => 'featured',
    'operator' => 'IN',
);

$args = array(
    'post_type'           => 'product',
    'post_status'         => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'      => 1,
    'meta_query'          => $meta_query,
    'tax_query'           => $tax_query,
);

$featured_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ($featured_query->have_posts()) {
    while ($featured_query->have_posts()) : 

        $featured_query->the_post();         
        $product = get_product( $featured_query->post->ID );
        $price = $product->get_price_html();            
        $sales_price_from = get_post_meta( $product->id, '_sale_price_dates_from', true );
        $sales_price_to   = get_post_meta( $product->id, '_sale_price_dates_to', true );
        $sales_price_date_from = date( "j.m.Y", $sales_price_from );
        $sales_price_date_to   = date( "j.m.Y", $sales_price_to );
        $sales_date = '<p class="offer_date">Angebot vom '.$sales_price_date_from.' bis '.$sales_price_date_to.'</p>';
        ?>

        <div class="wochenangebot"> 
        <h2>Wochenangebot</h2>
            <div class="wochenangebot_content">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                <?php echo $sales_date; ?>
                <?php var_dump($sales_price_to) ?>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </a>
            <span class="price"><?php echo $price; ?></span>

            <div class="legal-price-info">
            <p class="wc-gzd-additional-info">
                <span class="wc-gzd-additional-info tax-info variation_modified" style="display: inline;">inkl. MwSt.</span>
                <span class="wc-gzd-additional-info shipping-costs-info variation_modified" style="display: inline;">zzgl. <a href="https://nussundgenuss.de/unser-service/" target="_blank">Versandkosten</a></span>
            </p>
        </div>  
            <a class="button" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Hol es dir</a>
            </div>
            <aside>
            <?php 
                if ( has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID ) ) 
                    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog' ); 
                else 
                    echo '<img src="' . woocommerce_placeholder_img_src() . '" alt="Placeholder" >'; 
            ?>
            </aside>
        </div>

<?php   endwhile;
}
?>
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: First thank you for the answer. I have problems with both of the codes. I turned on wp_debug true and I get error messages. 

The one of the functions.php ist:
Notice: Undefined property: WP_Post_Type::$term_id in /homepages

The message of the other code is:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function date() on null

Do I have to rename the function date() to something else?

Comment: If you don't comment on my answer, I am not notified… I have updated the code once more… please try it again, and please leave some feed back on the comment zone below my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2**

The function `get_product()` is deprecated and replaced by `wc_get_product()` and there is many errors and mistakes in your code since Woocommerce 3. Try the following instead:

```
<?php
$meta_query  = WC()->query->get_meta_query();
$tax_query   = WC()->query->get_tax_query();
$tax_query[] = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
    'field'    => 'name',
    'terms'    => 'featured',
    'operator' => 'IN',
);

$args = array(
    'post_type'           => 'product',
    'post_status'         => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'      => 1,
    'meta_query'          => $meta_query,
    'tax_query'           => $tax_query,
);

$featured_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ($featured_query->have_posts()) {
    while ($featured_query->have_posts()) :
        $featured_query->the_post();

        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );
        $price   = $product->get_price_html();

        $sales_price_from = $product->get_date_on_sale_from();
        $sales_price_to   = $product->get_date_on_sale_to();

        if( ! empty($sales_price_from) || ! empty($sales_price_to) ){
            $sales_price_date_to   = $sales_price_from->date( "j.m.Y");
            $sales_price_date_from = $sales_price_to->date( "j.m.Y");
            $sales_date = '<p class="offer_date">Angebot vom '.$sales_price_date_from.' bis '.$sales_price_date_to.'</p>';
        } else {
            $sales_date = $sales_price_from = $sales_price_to = '';
        }
        ?>
        <div class="wochenangebot">
        <h2><?php _e("Wochenangebot"); ?></h2>
            <div class="wochenangebot_content">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                <?php echo $sales_date; ?>
                <?php var_dump($sales_price_to) ?>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </a>
            <span class="price"><?php echo $price; ?></span>

            <div class="legal-price-info">
            <p class="wc-gzd-additional-info">
                <span class="wc-gzd-additional-info tax-info variation_modified" style="display: inline;">inkl. MwSt.</span>
                <span class="wc-gzd-additional-info shipping-costs-info variation_modified" style="display: inline;">zzgl. <a href="https://nussundgenuss.de/unser-service/" target="_blank">Versandkosten</a></span>
            </p>
        </div>
            <a class="button" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Hol es dir</a>
            </div>
            <aside>
            <?php
                if ( has_post_thumbnail( get_the_id() ) )
                    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_id(), 'shop_catalog' );
                else
                    echo '<img src="' . woocommerce_placeholder_img_src() . '" alt="Placeholder" >';
            ?>
            </aside>
        </div>

<?php   endwhile;
}
?>
```

Tested and works with Woocommerce 3+

---

The linked code in your question is also outdated and should be like:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_html', 100, 2 );
function custom_price_html( $price, $product ) {

    if ( is_single() && $product->is_on_sale() && $sales_price_to != "" ) {

    $sales_price_from = $product->get_date_on_sale_from();
    $sales_price_to   = $product->get_date_on_sale_to();

    if( ! empty($sales_price_from) || ! empty($sales_price_to) ){
        $sales_price_date_to   = $sales_price_from->date( "j.m.Y");
        $sales_price_date_from = $sales_price_to->date( "j.m.Y");
        $sales_date = '<p class="offer_date">Angebot vom '.$sales_price_date_from.' bis '.$sales_price_date_to.'</p>';
    } else {
        $sales_date = $sales_price_from = $sales_price_to = '';
    }

        $price = str_replace( '</ins>', ' </ins> <b>(Offer from ' . $sales_price_date_from . ' till ' . $sales_price_date_to . ')</b>', $price );
    }

    return $price;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

Comment: I am sorry, it's the first time I use stackoverflow.
The code of the functions.php returns this error message:
Notice: Undefined variable: sales_price_to in /homepages/18/d735466922/htdocs/wp-content/themes/weta-child/functions.php on line 432
Do I have to use it in a loop?

On the other code the var_dump of sales_price_to again returns an empty string.

Comment: The code above is working, I tried it on another site. As a workaround for the site I need it, I added two fields with ACF, now I can display the date. I don't know what the problem ist... 
Thank you LoicTheAztec

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working with the Advanced Custom Fields, but now I've got the same problem with displaying the old price. I try again  something, maybe I have to open another question for this :/