# Display number of days to Sale end on Sale Products page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I got this code from here ( [Display woocommerce sale end date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23329518/display-woocommerce-sale-end-date) )

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_html', 100, 2 );
function custom_price_html( $price, $product )
{
    global $post;
    $sales_price_to = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_sale_price_dates_to', true);
    if(is_single() && $sales_price_to != "")
    {
        $sales_price_date_to = date("j M y", $sales_price_to);
        return str_replace( '</ins>', ' </ins> <b>(Sale ends '.$sales_price_date_to.')</b>', $price );
    }
    else
    {
        return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_price', $price );
    }
}
```

Works well like magic on the product page but I need help for this code to show days to end of sale instead. E.g. Sale ends in 1day/2days/3days etc. as the case may be. And also show on the Sale Products page not only on the Product page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do the job! Paste it in functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'add_end_sale_to_price', 100, 2 );
function add_end_sale_to_price( $price, $product )
{
    global $post;
    $sales_price_to = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_sale_price_dates_to', true);
    if($sales_price_to != "")
    {
        $now = time();
        $sales_price_date_to = date("Y-m-d", $sales_price_to);
        $end_date = strtotime($sales_price_date_to);
        $days_left = $end_date - $now;
        $days_left = floor($days_left / (60 * 60 * 24));

        return str_replace( '</ins>', ' </ins> <b>(Sale ends in '.$days_left.' days)</b>', $price );
    }
    else
    {
        return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_price', $price );
    }
}
```

Cheers,

Francesco

Comment: Yes! It works very perfectly! Have a look: https://www.tayobanjo.com/shop. Thanks.